# Spring Boot Mybatis Dynamic query

Tags: java, spring, dynamic, annotations, mybatis

Hello im pretty new to mybatis and is the first time im trying to use   with annotations in spring boot.

My code is something like this :

```
@Select("<script>"
            + "SELECT t.something, s.somewhat, "
            + "FROM t.table1 t "
            + "LEFT JOIN table2 s ON t.id = s.id "
            + "WHERE s.delete_date IS NULL "
            + "<if test=\"isnew\"> "
            + "AND t.insert_date = t.update_date "
            + "AND (t.score >= s.min_score AND t.score <= s.max_score) "
            + "</if>"
            + "union "
            + "ANOTHER SIMILAR QUERY WITH ANOTHER <IF> + "</script>")
List<Map<String, Object>> methodName(@Param("isnew") Boolean isNew);
```

This is the error.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Could not find value method on SQL annotation.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 822;`

Im almost sure there is an error of syntax very predictable but I cant find it.
Here are some examples of what I tried, none of them works:

- "<if test="isnew = true">"
- "<if test="isnew == true">"
- "<if test="isnew != false">"
- "<if test="isnew"> "
- "<if test=#{isnew}"> "
- "<if #{isnew} = true> "

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may have the same problem this is the solution:

You have to escape the character **<** , because mybatis takes it as an unopened tag, **&lt** will work :

````
            + "SELECT t.something, s.somewhat, "
            + "FROM t.table1 t "
            + "LEFT JOIN table2 s ON t.id = s.id "
            + "WHERE s.delete_date IS NULL "
            + "<if test=\"isnew\"> "
            + "AND t.insert_date = t.update_date "
            + "AND (t.score >= s.min_score AND t.score lt;= s.max_score) "
            + "</if>"
            + "union "
            + "ANOTHER SIMILAR QUERY WITH ANOTHER <IF> + "</script>")
List<Map<String, Object>> methodName(@Param("isnew") Boolean isNew);```
````